# Classes Missing in Emgcv 3.1 when compared with Emgucv 2.4.10

Tags: c#, .net, emgucv

Earlier i was using Emgucv 2.4.10 version now i wanted to upgrade it to the 3.1 so that it can support in Raspberry Pi

What i found is there are some Classes are missing such as

```
#region Blob Variables
BlobTrackerAutoParam<Bgr> param = new BlobTrackerAutoParam<Bgr>();
FGDetector<Bgr> FgDetector = new FGDetector<Bgr>(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.FORGROUND_DETECTOR_TYPE.FGD);
BlobDetector blobDetector = new BlobDetector(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BLOB_DETECTOR_TYPE.Simple);
BlobTracker blobTracker = new BlobTracker(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BLOBTRACKER_TYPE.CC);
BlobTrackPostProc btpp = new BlobTrackPostProc(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BLOB_POST_PROCESS_TYPE.Kalman);
BlobTrackerAuto<Bgr> tracker;
Image<Gray, Byte> ProcessedImage;
#endregion
```

Had they changed the classe name in 3.1 update are they any alternative that i can make us to full fill my requirments.

Answer (score 0):

All classess are in namespace
`Emgu.CV.World`
Use the documentation site to update your project (I've been through this too :D)
[Link to your search](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/search.html?SearchText=blob)
[Link to whole documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/8dee1f02-8c8a-4e37-87f4-05e10c39f27d.htm)

Make sure to never leave the '3.1' section of it :) 
Good luck

Comment: still i am not able to get what alternative i have to use. i am able to detect the blob but blob Label is gradually increasing.

Answer (score 0):

I hav experienced similar problem. I want to use kalman filter but 'kalman' class is not exist in 3.1 version.

So, I have traced source in emgucv.cv folder and find that kalman.cs class is not exist in 3.1 version. Anyway...I have edit EmguCV source and solve problem.

1) Copy kalman class from old version
2) edit PvInvoke\CvInvoke.cs (add dll load part for kalman filter)
3) add dlls for CvInvoke (video, core, imgproc dlls)